To which extent I should let my PI know that I am not feeling very well with my PhD study
I am a first-year international PhD student at a U.S. university, and as the semester approaches its end, I am planning to meet with my PI to reflect on how my first semester has been. While my research is progressing very well, I’ve faced some significant personal and academic challenges earlier this semester, and I’m unsure how much I should share with my advisor.
Two key factors have contributed to these struggles:

The graduate-level classes I’m taking are general and not closely aligned with my research focus. This has left me feeling unmotivated about coursework, and I find it challenging to balance my time between classes and research.

My father passed away from cancer before I moved to the U.S. earlier this year. Navigating this loss while adapting to a new environment has been very difficult, and it has impacted my academic performance at times. Additionally, as an STEM-majored student, I only have a one-year student visa studying in the US. The optimal solution for my academic path is to stay here in the US until I graduate, but I’m not sure my mental health can support me through the next 5 years of living abroad.


I recognize that my advisor is not necessarily the right person to address mental health concerns, and I don’t want to burden him with these issues or give the impression that I’m struggling, as my research is going well. However, I also feel that some transparency about these challenges might be important. To what extent should I share these personal struggles with my PI, and how can I communicate this in a way that maintains his confidence in my work while addressing my concerns?

Do you need to pass comprehensive/qualifying exams to get the degree as is common in the US?

Another question suggests that the OP studies Physics.

@Buffy Yes, I need to pass 3 comprehensive exams.

First your general classes are meant to give you a broad overview of physics. Most of them will not directly relate to your research topic. If you want to stay in academia you will most likely have to teach at some point, and generally not about your research. The qualifying exams exist to test this general mastery. It is normal that some of them are not as exciting to you as you research area but you can't completely neglect them.
Second the family issues. You don't have to stay in the US consecutively for the full 5 years to finish your degree. You can go home and apply for a new visa to continue your studies. In general this should be granted but there is some risk involved that it will not or that it will take longer than anticipated. Unfortunately these risks depend primarily on what country is your home country and US politics and are thus out of your (and your universities) control. Having your father pass away is definitely a reason where your university, your department and your PI should understand that you want to travel home. You can try to talk to the international office in your university for counsel but in the end you have to decide yourself whether you want to travel home or not.

You should meet with your advisor regularly. I'd suggest weekly, though if you both prefer a different schedule that's fine, but once a semester isn't going to work. Your topic of conversation should be your progress in research. I don't know how you would have this conversation without mentioning things that bother you.
PhDs are very specialized. It's not possible to have courses that are more than general with respect to a PhD. If there is more than just you in the class then it can't relate too closely to your PhD because you are pushing the field down your own personal path. You can have this conversation with your advisor though and they can tell you the same thing.
I'm not clear on what the relationship between staying in the US and your PhD is. I would assume you need to be in the US physically to continue, so leaving is a discussion about quitting. If you don't think that's the case it's definitely something you need to discuss before you make a decision.
It's not really your advisor's job to manage your overall mental health - I'd highly recommend seeing a therapist or similar mental health professional. It's likely your school has resources. That said, personally I think it's worth talking about these sorts of things at a high level with your advisor so they understand where you are at. But, your focus should be on moving forward and making satisfactory progress, not on making excuses for past unsatisfactory progress. If there's something you need right now to help you move forward, you can ask for that.

Given this is a 1st year PhD student, they may not have a research advisor yet, just a default 1st-year-grad-student advisor who advises them on what courses to take and whom they should talk to as part of beginning the process of finding a research area and research advisor.  In that case, meeting with them once a semester is entirely appropriate (though they should meet more if there are specific issues to discuss).

Thanks for the answer! I have an assigned advisor and we have weekly meetings to discuss the research, the research is going well and I only presented research-related topics during the discussion, I was trying to figure out whether I should also let him know of some of my personal struggles.

@AlexanderWoo They described them as their PI which I think implies they're a research mentor and not just a temporary advisor.

@IGY I don't think things that impact your work are merely personal struggles - especially the things that directly involve your graduate studies.

It’s important to remember that your PhD studies are indeed a job—one that comes with unique pressures and demands. Just as in any workplace, it’s appropriate and necessary to communicate with your "employer," in this case, your PI, when you're unwell or facing significant challenges. Transparency, when handled thoughtfully, strengthens trust and collaboration, rather than weakening it.
Your research progress speaks volumes about your dedication and capability, even in the face of personal hardship. Sharing some context about your journey this semester can help your advisor understand the resilience you’ve shown and the hurdles you’ve overcome. For instance, you might start the conversation by focusing on the positive—highlighting your research progress and how you’ve adapted to this new phase of your life—before briefly mentioning the challenges you've faced. Here’s an example of how you could approach this:
"This first semester has been a significant adjustment for me, and I feel that my research is progressing well despite some initial challenges. I wanted to share that balancing coursework, which feels less directly tied to my research, has been an adjustment, and I’m working on strategies to better manage my time. Additionally, I’ve been navigating a major personal loss earlier this year and adapting to a new environment. It has been a lot to manage, but I’m committed to making the most of this opportunity and continuing to grow. I wanted to share this context with you, as I value open communication and your guidance as my mentor."
This kind of framing communicates your challenges while also showing your resolve and proactive mindset.
Additionally, do consider seeking support from counseling services at your university or from trusted peers. You’re not alone, and finding spaces where you can process these feelings will help lighten the burden. Compassion is a cornerstone of a healthy mentor-student relationship, and any understanding PI will appreciate your openness and resilience. It’s okay to ask for help—it’s a sign of strength, not weakness.

Other answers here have addressed the fact that counseling is probably a needed element, and that, yes, discussions with your supervisor can be helpful, but primarily in relation to your research. I want to say something about your coursework.
In the US it is pretty typical, if not universal, to have required coursework in a doctoral program. These courses are designed, primarily, to help you get through comprehensive/qualifying exams. You also probably have a very limited number of attempts to pass those exams, and failing any of them (perhaps twice), ends your scholarship at that place.
The exams, in turn, are normally designed to assure that a candidate has a broad view of their overall field. So, the courses aren't like the research and dissertation, which are designed to be narrow. So, a US doctorate in many fields requires both breadth (field as a whole) and depth (very narrow expertise in a sub-field). Both are considered essential.
Thus, your supervisor isn't going to be able to solve the coursework problem for you. The program is what it is, and advisors have no control over it. They might not even be involved in any oral exams that might occur as part of "comps".
It may be that you need some advice on time management. It may be that you need to accept the philosophy behind the program design and work hard on the coursework, with the real goal of passing comps. They can be very difficult.
I'll guess that as an international student, you started here with a masters. Most US students don't, having only a bachelors. In many places research for these students doesn't really begin until they have done the coursework and, perhaps, passed comps already. If you start with a masters it can be quite a bit more compressed. Just a fact of life that you have to deal with.
But various kinds of counseling, both for personal issues and for time management, might be the key to moving forward effectively. Your supervisor probably can't help much with that other than giving encouragement, but it is still wise to keep in contact with them.
